# Reemplazar el uso de "var" al crear una variable en C# 2.0

Tags: c#, variables, clase

Buenas mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
var items = new Normaslist();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        //using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
```

en el codigo mostrado defino una variable **items** como una clase **Normaslist()**

```
[Serializable()]
public class Normaslist
{

public Normaslist()
{
    //Lista = new List<Normalegal>();
}

public List<Normalegal> Lista = new List<Normalegal>();//{ get { return this.p_lista; } set { this.p_lista= value; }}
private List<Normalegal> p_lista;

public string TotalRowsn { get { return this.p_TotalRowsn; } set { this.p_TotalRowsn = value; } }
private string p_TotalRowsn;

public string TotalPagesn { get { return this.p_TotalPagesn; } set { this.p_TotalPagesn = value; } }
private string p_TotalPagesn;


}
```

He probado reemplazando la definición de **items** con

```
    Normaslist items = new Normaslist();
```

También con

```
    Normaslist items = Activator.CreateInstance<Normaslist>();
```

Ambos funcionan normalmente cuando los compilo en c# 4.0 pero al momento de compilarlo con c#2.0 no funciona correctamente. No muestra errores de compilación tampoco. Quisiera saber si es la manera correcta de definir la variable **items** sin usar **var** en **c #2.0**

Answer (score 1):

Se puede a partir de la versión 3 de C#:

> A partir de Visual C# 3.0, las variables que se declaran en el ámbito de método pueden tener un "tipo" **var** implícito.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var

```
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())           //Implícita
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) //Explícita
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta estimado , hay alguna manera de declarar mi variable de forma explicita ?

Comment: respuesta edita :)

Comment: ya lo estas haciendo de forma explicita en tu pregunta.